# Can I download s3 objects locally with custom naming?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, aws-sdk, aws-cli

Using the CLI you can use
`aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/1234_client/dev/my.hprof.gz ./my_file_naming_is_custom.hprof.gz`

The above gives you a renamed file of the object locally. I want to do the same in boto3.

With the SDK (boto3) I have a bucket and download defined as such:

```
s3_resource = session.resource('s3', region_name=region)
my_bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(log_destination)
my_cur_dir = os.getcwd()
for s3_object in my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=prefix):
       path, filename = os.path.split(s3_object.key)
             my_bucket.download_file(s3_object.key, filename)
```

Currently, this downloads the object as the 'key' and creates a new directory locally with the object inside (ie 1234_client/dev/my.hprof.gz). Is there a way to name the file downloaded locally using boto3 (download object 1234_client/dev/my.hprof.gz as ./this_is_my_file.hprof.gz)? I didn't find anything in the docs.

Comment: `download_file` takes to values, the first is the name of the object in S3, the second, the one you're passing in `filename` to is the name to write to disk locally.  Pass something else in for this value if you want a different filename.

Comment: Got this to work in a single line. Attempting to implement it now. Not sure why I split up defining the bucket and downloading the file separately. I should be passing all 3 args in the ```download_file``` call.

Comment: Feel free to add your own Answer to help future readers.